# Бот не отправляет фотографии [TeleBot, Python]

Tags: python, telebot

Делал бота по истории села,нужно чтобы бот отправлял сообщения но он этого не делает

```
@tb.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def on_click(message):
    file1 = open('/home/elbzrd/Рабочий стол/project/Programs/bot/проект по технологии/file_btn3.png', 'rb')

    if message.text == 'Народное предание':
        tb.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Село Носовая расположено в левобережной части Краснобаковского района Нижегородской области. Сохраняется народное предание, что на этом месте когда-то были три селения: марийское, татарское и русское, основанное купцом Носовым.')
    elif message.text == 'Первое упоминание о селе':
        tb.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Первое упоминание о селе начинается с 1773 года. Это была дача помещицы Елены Алексеевны Долгоруковой, где хранится запись генерального межевания под номером 31.')
    elif message.text == 'Первая церковь':
        tb.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Село разделяет небольшая речка Боровка, в которую впадает Медяна. Они, сливаясь воедино, попадают в реку Уста. В 1933 году построена первая церковь, где священником был Руфин Философ Философьевич.')
        tb.send_photo(message.chat.id, file1)
    elif message.text == 'Место работы современных жителей села':
        tb.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В селе работают лесопромышленные предприятия. Больше работы нет. Разве что в магазинах и бюджетных учреждениях.')
```

Comment: А что в консоли? И, почему вы не по file_id отправляете сообщение?

Comment: .в консоли пусто, он просто отправляет текст. Как отправить по file_id?

Comment: Картинка должна выдаваться только на текст "Первая церковь". Сначала нужно отправить боту картинку, получить ее file_id и этот file_id подставлять туда, где нужна отправка фото

Comment: Тоесть я не могу отправить файл ,если он лежит у меня на пк. Мне нужно обязательно сначала получить айди и только потом отправлять?

Comment: Ну почему не можешь? Можешь. Но, рекомендованный способ отправит фото по file_id. Так сложно сказать, почему с пк не отправляется, без логов-то. Предполагаю, что какая-то проблема с путем к файлу